# How can i retrieve IP Address of a Kafka node using Jmx query?

Tags: apache-kafka, jmx, mbeans

I am monitoring Kafka by configuring JMX. I need IP address of the node where Kafka is being monitored. I am not being able to get MBean name to query for IP. how can I do it?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried so far.

Comment: I have tried getting some metrics of Kafka. And  I am able to retrieve many more like Messages in per second, BytesInPerSec, etc using query like jmxQuery=[JMXQuery("kafka.server:type=BrokerTopicMetrics,name=MessagesInPerSec",                    metric_name="kafka_server_BrokerTopicMetrics_MessagesInPerSec_Count",attribute="*")] as per my requirement.